# When calling to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() I'm getting an error

Tags: php, mysql

i got this issue, and i cant resolve it, i surf all the answers of the sites but i can resolve it, my web hosting is hostinger.com

```
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is php code, thanks

Comment: just make sure you have `mysqlnd` on your env

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` to see if there's a section labelled `mysqlnd`. This component (the MySQL Native Driver) is [required for this function to work](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.get-result-mysqlnd).

Comment: Sorry, but where i check that, the output of phpinfo(), thanks!!!

Comment: I read in some place, that the code can change, but i dont know how??

Comment: How i use bind_result and fetch, instead of get_result, in my code?